# About elements "factorization" in Clifford Algebras

Tags: lorentz-symmetry, clifford-algebra

the article linked below is very instructive and advanced about real Clifford Algebras, and their relationship with Lorentz group. After a general introduction of a Clifford algebra, $\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)$, over a real, finite dimensional vector space $V$ with a non-degenerate quadratic form $\Phi$ as the quotient algebra:
$$\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)\sim\frac{\mathcal{T}(V)}{\mathcal{I}(V,\Phi)}$$
where $\mathcal{T}(V)$ is the tensor algebra of $V$ and $\mathcal{I}(V,\Phi)$ is the bilateral ideal generated by all elements of the form:
$$v \otimes v - \Phi(v)·\mathbb{1}\quad,\quad v \in V$$
and after presenting all the implications of this definition, the article go straight to define an automorphism (the is also an involution) $\alpha:\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)\rightarrow\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)$ as:
$$\alpha(i(v)):=-i(v)$$
where the map $i:V\rightarrow\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)$ is an injection. Here, in the proof of $\alpha$ as an involution, the authors write that:

> [...]. Furthermore, every $x\in\mathcal{Cl}(V,\Phi)$ can be written as:
>   $$x=x_1···x_m$$
>   with $x_j \in i(V)$ [...].

Now, my question is: if $\mathcal{T}(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{i=0}^{n}V^{\otimes i}$, shouldn't $x$ be a superposition of "polynomials" of elements of $i(V)$ rather than "monomials" as above? If not, how can I demonstrate this?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506011

Comment: $\alpha$ is linear, right? In that case studying it on monomials should be enough.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is linear and, with the automorphism properties, i thought it would be sufficient to prove that it is an involution, too. However, the statement in the article is pretty strong and the doubt that it is related with the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem is haunting me.

Comment: I believe the author implicitly means to say "every $x$ is of the form [...] *or linear combinations thereof*."

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, but my question was not about the demostration of $\alpha$ as an involution. I was worried about if the statement used in that demoatration is actually right. Maybe it can be reformulated in other words as: can the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem be extende to the whole Clifford Algebra?

Comment: If you are referring to the statement in yellow I think it's not right but the author meant what I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm also not following how the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem is related to Clifford algebras and how would it help to show that yellow paragraph.

Comment: Well there exist a subset of the Clifford Algebra that respect the group properties, called thereof the Clifford Group, and that can be mapped onto  the indefinite orthogonal group, $O(t,s)$, with an homomorphism. On this latter group, the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem says that every rotation can be factorized in a set of reflections. Reflections, in the Clifford group, are just elements of the $i(V)$ injection explained above, with some specification due to the homomorphism map. So in the Clifford Group every elements is exactly a monomial of some grade in elements of $i(V)$.

Comment: Clarification: In the Clifford Group every element can be _**written**_ as a monomial of some grade in elements of $i(v)$. @MannyC